# Are there any other ships that have an alphabetical suffix?

Tags: star-trek

We know there's been a lot of *Enterprises* - the NX-01, Original (TOS), the A, B, C, D and E at least (ignoring the F from Star Trek Online and the J from *Enterprise*).  But is Enterprise the only ship name to have been christened multiple times?  Ie have there been other ships labelled '(Insert ships' name here)-A' or more in any works (I will include all the television series', books, fan-made materials - anything basically)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There have been ships that bear the same name with different registry numbers like the Excelsior, which had NCC-2000, and NCC-21445.  There were at least 3 ships with name USS reg: Defiant NCC-1764, NX-74205, NCC-75633.  There have also been three USS Constellations: NCC-1017, NX-1974 and NCC-55817.

But if you are primarily concerned about a following letter then I found two examples pretty quickly.

- The [USS Yamato](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Yamato) had a registry number of NCC-1305-E.
- The [USS Relativity](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Relativity) had NCV-474439-G.

Answer (score 3):

In regards to expanded universe (books, comics,games etc) starships, there's probably too many to give a complete answer, but here are a few I remember:

- [Saratoga-A](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Saratoga_%28NCC-31911-A%29), replacing Ben Sisko's Saratoga.
- [Stargazer-A](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Stargazer_%28Intrepid_class%29) replacing Picard's Stargazer
- [Excalibur-A](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Excalibur_%28NCC-26517-A%29) replacing Mackenzie Calhoun's Excalibur.

More can be found here at [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page), a Star Trek expanded universe wiki.

I'm sure I remember reading somewhere that, in-universe, the use of letters on the registry was meant to be a unique thing in honour of Kirk's Enterprise, but I can't find the reference for that, and it might not be true in-universe anyway. In the notes for [U.S.S Yamato](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Yamato#Registry) at Memory Alpha they mention how there was confusion for it's number, as the model built to blow up in 'Contagion' was meant to show NCC-71807 but the dialogue in 'Where Silence Has Lease' says NCC-1305-E, so it's debatable what's canon there. But on the other hand, the second [Defiant](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Defiant_%282375%29#Background_information) that shows up in DS9 was meant to be Defiant-A but it came down to a budgetary issue that stopped it.